# Comparing timestamp and Carbon::now()->toTimeString() without seconds

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I am building a query which will be executed every minute when the `daily_at` time and the current time are equal. The `daily_at` variable is a timestamp of for example `10:05:33`.

I want the `where` clause in the query to pass when the hour and minute are the same, but not the second else almost non will be executed. The where clause which I have now:

```
DB::table('restaurants')
   ->where('schedule', '=', $schedule)
   ->where('active', '=', 1)
   ->whereDate('start_at', '<=', Carbon::today())
   ->where('daily_at', '=', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
   .....
```

Could someone help me to adjust the `where` clause to ignore the seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
DB::table('restaurants')
->where('schedule', '=', $schedule)
->where('active', '=', 1)
->whereDate('start_at', '<=', Carbon::today())
->where('daily_at', '=', Carbon::now()->format('H:i'))
```

One more way:

```
DB::table('restaurants')
    ->where('schedule', '=', $schedule)
    ->where('active', '=', 1)
    ->whereDate('start_at', '<=', Carbon::today())
    ->where('daily_at', '=', Carbon::createFromTime(Carbon::now()->hour,Carbon::now()->minute,00)->format('H:i:s'))
```

You can pass an extra argument to set timezone:

```
Carbon::createFromTime(Carbon::now()->hour,Carbon::now()->minute,00,'Example/Zone')->format('H:i:s')
```

Comment: Great! Now I only need to get the hour and minute from the daily_at

Comment: Nice! What do you need exactly? Maybe I can help you. Would you set mine answer as correct answer?

Comment: The `daily_at` value right now is for example H:i:s. I need to lose the seconds from the `daily_at` and only have the H:i to make the comparison pass!

Comment: You can set the `daily_at` seconds value to 00 and try with the updated answer method

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You can use `setSeconds(int $value)` method:

```php
Carbon::now()->setSeconds(0)->toTimeString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
DB::table('restaurants')
->where('schedule', '=', $schedule)
->where('active', '=', 1)
->whereDate('start_at', '<=', Carbon::today())
->where('daily_at', '=', Carbon::now('Y-m-d H:i')->toTimeString())
use this code
```

Comment: This is not working: `Unknown or bad timezone (Y-m-d H:i)`. And the `daily_at` doesn't have a Y-m-d, so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this way:

```
whereRaw(DATE_FORMAT(daily_at, "%H:%i") = Carbon::now()->format('H:i'))
```

So final query would be,

```
DB::table('restaurants')
->where('schedule', '=', $schedule)
->where('active', '=', 1)
->whereDate('start_at', '<=', Carbon::today())
->where('daily_at', '=', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
->whereRaw(DATE_FORMAT(daily_at, "%H:%i") = Carbon::now()->format('H:i'))
```